# Pass ZMQ context to embedded Lua from C

Tags: c, lua, zeromq

In my C application I have a single ZMQ context, which I would like to share with all Lua States. I use Lua version 5.2 and ZMQ version 3.2.

I would like to use an already available binding for Lua, like lzmq.

For example:

```
// create ZMQ context
void *ctx = zmq_ctx_new();
...
// create Lua State
lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
...
// push the context or something
lua_setglobal(L, "MY_ZMQ_CONTEXT");
```

then being able to somehow use that ZMQ context in Lua (example using lzmq):

```
local zmq = require "lzmq"
require "utils"

print_version(zmq)

local ctx = MY_ZMQ_CONTEXT -- ???

local skt = ctx:socket{zmq.REQ,
    linger = 0, rcvtimeo = 1000;
    connect = "inproc://hello";
}

skt:send("hello from cli")
print_msg("recv: ",skt:recv())

skt:close()
```

How would I do something like this? either using lzmq or any other ZMQ Lua bindings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set lightuserda and use init_ctx function.

```
lua_pushlightuserdata(L, ctx);
lua_setglobal(L, "MY_ZMQ_CONTEXT");

local zmq = require "lzmq"
local ctx = zmq.init_ctx(MY_ZMQ_CONTEXT)
```

In this case you can not close context from Lua.
I have idea add this functionality in next version.

lzmq also has C functoin `LUAZMQ_EXPORT int luazmq_context (lua_State *L, void *ctx, unsigned char own)`.
You can wrap contex like this.

```
luazmq_contex(L, ctx, 0);
// or if you want hase ability to destroy contex from Lua
// luazmq_contex(L, ctx, 1);

// MY_ZMQ_CONTEXT is lzmq context
lua_setglobal(L, "MY_ZMQ_CONTEXT");
```

Comment: After debugging my code for a while, I came to the conclusion that the above gives me a segmentation fault. My test snippet: http://pastebin.com/2hh9u4g5 and here's a backtrace: http://pastebin.com/PFdxbUhv . Do note that "./lzmq.so" is compiled from the master branch on github, and creating a context in Lua and using that works. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I just run this test on my Windows system and it works. Also init_ctx uses in lzmq.lthread module and also tested in several modules on Travis. May be you link application and lzmq to different version of libzmq. Error raize from libzmq code.

Comment: Sorry. I'll check it again.

Comment: I should have mentioned this, I am developing on Debian Wheezy (GNU/Linux). I only have libzmq3-dev installed, so there should be no version conflict as I compile both my application and lzmq github master (libzmq3-dev:amd64 3.2.3). I'll do some further tests in a virtual machine, both windows and gnu/linux. Edit: libzmq3-dev is available from wheezy-backports.

Comment: I forgot. init_ctx recive pointer to lzmq contex not on raw zmq context. I think i can fix it. Just do several tests. Code is https://github.com/moteus/lzmq/blob/master/src/zcontext.c#L98.

Comment: Please try current master

Comment: All my tests and my program execute correctly, thanks! If I encounter any problems in the future I will report them.